# Diferenças entre compilar e recompilar?

Tags: visual-studio, compilação, ide

Alguns IDEs como o Visual Studio possuem as opções de compilar e de recompilar o projeto, qual a diferença entre as duas e o que elas executam de diferente? E quando cada uma deve ser usada?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Imagino que está falando de *build* e *rebuild* que é um pouco diferente de compilar e recompilar.

A semântica exata pode variar e nem é tanto o IDE, é o sistema de construção de projetos que o IDE reproduz em GUI.

Construir aproveita o que já tem, é chamada de construção incremental. Por  exemplo, tudo que ele detecta que não precisa para gerar um novo executável ele não gera. Em geral isso é verificado quando o horário do que foi mudado no código e que o executável está com horário anterior, precisa gerar um novo.

Reconstruir começa tudo do zero como se nada tivesse sido feito com aquilo antes, o que obviamente demora mais, mas evita pegar algo que já está defasado.

Answer (score 14):

Se estiver falando de C# e VB.Net (não posso afirmar outros): a principal diferença é que o *rebuild* (recompilar) faz um *clean* no projeto e 
depois faz um *build* (compilar).

Enquanto o *build* vai verificar todos os arquivos que foram alterados e tentar compilar somente aquilo que foi modificado. *Rebuild* vai compilar tudo do zero.